# Check for empty JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, string, jformattedtextfield

I'm new here, and I'd like some help on a small Java project I'm doing. This is the code snippet I need help with:

```
private void CalculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                
{                                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    float Principal, Rate, Time, Result, Temp;

    Principal = Float.valueOf(PrincipalTextField.getText());
    Rate = Float.valueOf(RateTextField.getText());
    Time = Float.valueOf(TimeTextField.getText());

    Temp = (float) Math.pow((1 + Rate / 100), Time);
    Result = Principal * Temp;
    ResultTextField.setText(String.valueOf(Result));
}
```

I'd like to check if PrincipalTextField, OR RateTextField, OR TimeTextField aren't filled by the user, and if so, display a dialog box that asks him/her to recheck them. The text fields are JFormattedTextField variables. I realise that I can do this with a if/else or a while loop, but I'm not sure how to set about doing so. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

- The `getText()` returns you a String value. So you can always invoke `length()` and check whether the length comes to 0 or not. (*I would suggest calling `trim()` on the String before calling `length()` to remove any whitespaces)
- Next if any of the length comes to be zero, what you want to do is display a *Dialog Box*. This you can do by calling `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()`. You can read more about "How to Make Dialogs" [over here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

So, you would do something like this:

```
String principalText = PrincipalTextField.getText();
String rateText = RateTextField.getText();
String timeText = TimeTextField.getText();

if(principalText.trim().length == 0 || rateText.trim().length == 0 || timeText.trim().length == 0){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOUR_ERROR_MSG", "ERROR_TITLE", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

This might be off-topic, but I would suggest looking at [Java Naming Convention](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/naming.html). The convention for variables is to compose variable names using *mixed case letters* starting with a *lower case letter*

Comment: Ah, thank you. I had experimented with the trim() and length() methods, but it seems that I didn't use them properly. The thing about naming convention is new... Isn't it only methods that start with lower case letters and then uppercase,  as in "showMessageDialog"? I'm also learning Objective-C, where variables are capitalised the way I've done it. Maybe I just got confused. But thank you very much.

Comment: @user1654223: Nope, variables also follow the same pattern. But glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

1. you miss reason for why there is [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)
2. have to set `Number Formatter` for `JFormattedTextField`, then

   - you not need to parsing `Float value` (better could be to use double)
   - empty coudl be 0 (zero) value by default
   - take value in the form     `((Number)PrincipalTextField.getValue()).floatValue();`
3. look at code example for tutorial,

Answer (score 1):

Also consider subclassing [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html), as discussed in [*Validating Input*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification). There's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2241997/230513).