# Combining InputVerifiers

Tags: java, swing, input, validation

Does the Swing API have classes which combine InputVerifiers? For example, I have three InputVerifiers in my current project:

1. NotEmptyInputVerifier - verifies that a textfield is not empty
2. PositiveIntegerInputVerifier - verifies that a text field contains a positive integer
3. YearInputVerifier - verifies that a text field contains a four digit year

NotEmptyInputVerifier needs to be used for all input, whether Strings or numerical. PositiveIntegerInput needs to check that the text field is not empty *and* additionally check that the input string only contains digits. YearInputVerifier needs to also check that the input is exactly four digits, with the leading digit non-zero.

Now each of these builds on the other. I can easily implement this with composition or inheritence. It seems like this pattern would come up quite often in Swing applications and I think a little wrapper class, say AndInputVerifier, would be useful enough to belong in the Swing API. I haven't been able to find one, though, so I think it doesn't exist. ;-(

If not in the Swing API, does anyone know if this exists in a third-party package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) does not define any sub-class for InputVerifier, so it does not exist as such in a JVM.

Now, it is really not complex to achieve what you want:

```
import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class CombinedInputVerifier extends InputVerifier {

    private InputVerifier[] verifiers;

    public CombinedInputVerifier(InputVerifier... verifiers) {
        this.verifiers = verifiers;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        for (InputVerifier verifier : verifiers) {
            if (!verifier.verify(input)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yah, that's what I thought from what I saw in the JavaDocs as well. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2241997/230513) that accepts multiple date formats.