# JFormattedTextField and short time format

Tags: java, swing, date, simpledateformat, jformattedtextfield

I have a `JFormattedTextField` in my form, and I've set it's form to short time: `MM/dd/yyyy`.

When I type some date that contains two numbers in the day part, or in the month part, or four numbers in the year part, the `JFormattedTextField`  doesn't accept the changes.

For example if I typed : `30/11/2013` I get : `6/11/15`.

but if I typed : `6/5/10` it accepts the changes.

Please, if someone tells me how could I solve this problem, I'll be thankful.

## EDIT :

This is a simple SSCCE :

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jFormattedTextField1 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jFormattedTextField1.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DateFormatter(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"))));

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Date :");

        jLabel2.setText("Output :");

        jLabel3.setText("Click here to see the output");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 284, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1))
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(125, 125, 125))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jTextField1.setText(jFormattedTextField1.getText());
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;

}
```

Comment: Got a working example or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer please see the modification I made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a `SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")`, the [*lenient*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) interpretation of the `Calendar` value `30/11/2013` is `6/11/2015`. You can defeat this behavior by specifying `setLenient(false)` in the format used to construct your `JFormattedTextField`.

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2241997/230513), an `InputVerifier` is used to check a `List<SimpleDateFormat>` for valid entries. For example,

```
static {
    validForms.add(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"));
    validForms.add(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy"));
    for (SimpleDateFormat f : validForms) {
        f.setLenient(false);
    }
}
```

Addendum: In your updated example,

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
f.setLenient(false);
jFormattedTextField1.setFormatterFactory(
    new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(
        new javax.swing.text.DateFormatter(f)));
```

SSCCE, for reference:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jFormattedTextField1 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SimpleDateFormat f = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        f.setLenient(false);
        jFormattedTextField1.setFormatterFactory(
            new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(
            new javax.swing.text.DateFormatter(f)));

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Date :");

        jLabel2.setText("Output :");

        jLabel3.setText("Click here to see the output");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 284, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1))
            .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(125, 125, 125)))));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jTextField1.setText(jFormattedTextField1.getText());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
}
```

Comment: what is this variable : `validForms`

Comment: As shown in the example cited, it's a `List<SimpleDateFormat>`.

Comment: please see the modification I made to my post, I don"t know how to use this code you've gave me

Comment: You should invoke `setLenient(false)` on the (anonymous) `SimpleDateFormat` instance passed to `DefaultFormatterFactory`.

Comment: I got this error :

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at testdate.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:13)`