# getting format of JFormatTextField

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I've several text fields with certain formats: percent format, date format, etc:

```
     DateFormat dfm= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     textField = new JFormattedTextField(dfm);
```

Later I want to check what format is being used in a textField. I have checked if there is a method `textField.getFormat()` or similar. Didn't see anything relevant. Is there a way to know this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the source code, your `Format` is converted to a `JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory`

```
public JFormattedTextField(java.text.Format format) {
  this();
  setFormatterFactory(getDefaultFormatterFactory(format));
}
```

There is a getter available on `JFormattedTextField` to retrieve this `JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory` afterwards. This `JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory` gives you access to a `JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter`.

However, you can no longer access your actual `Format` instance. Depending on why you need it, the `JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter` might be sufficient

Comment: If the given textfield uses date format then when submit button is pressed, text retrieved from textfield.getText(),which is String, needs to be formatted back to DateFormat:

   DateFormat dfm= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   Date a = dfm.parse(textfield.getText());

Comment: +1 @Nazerke: Also consider `InputVerifier`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2241997/230513).

Comment: interesting that official Oracle tutorial (as always) say about