# DateFormatter with JFormattedTextField how to type in only a valid date

Tags: java, swing, simpledateformat, jformattedtextfield

I want to make my `JFormattedTextField` take only valid numbers from the keyboard. If I choose a date format "dd-mm-yyyy", when I start typing I can get only 0,1,2 or 3 as the first digit in day's number. My code below, not only does not do that, but it allows me to type anything, without bothering to put in the "-" character. On lost focus, however, the typed date disappears unless it's in the valid format(which also means I need to type "-" myself.

My question is: can I modify this code in a simple way, without adding new `MaskedFormatters` or writing some input verifiers, such that I can only type the date in the correct format and nothing else, without having to type the "-" characters?

As I read in other posts, many people recommend using `JSpinners` instead of this, but I'll think of that only if I can't do what I want with the `JFormattedTextField`.

This is the subclassed `JFormattedTextField`:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.*; //for the date format
    import javax.swing.text.*;//date formatter

    public class RomDateField extends JFormattedTextField{

        public RomDateField(){

        super();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        DateFormatter df=new DateFormatter(sdf);
        //df.setAllowsInvalid(false); //with this you can't type at all
        df.setOverwriteMode(true);
        df.setCommitsOnValidEdit(true);
        setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(df));
        }
    }
```

and the main class:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class TestDates{

        JLabel jl=new JLabel("Date:");
        JFrame jf=new JFrame("Test DateFormatter with JFormattedTextField");
        RomDateField jtf=new RomDateField();
        JButton jb=new JButton("Lose Focus");
        JPanel pane=new JPanel();

        public TestDates(){

            jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            pane.add(jl);
            jtf.setColumns(20);
            pane.add(jtf);
            pane.add(jb);

            jf.add(pane);
            jf.pack();
            jf.setVisible(true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    TestDates tdate=new TestDates();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: use JSpinner with SpinnerDateModel

Comment: Yes, it looks like it. Actually, it looks better than I could have achieved with JFormattedTextField.

Comment: You can accept multiple formats as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2241997/230513).