# How to change foreground/text color of JFormattedTextField on its input text not obeying the RegEx format?

Tags: java, swing

I am following, http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/RegexFormatterwithaJFormattedTextField.htm. In the given example, How to change foreground/text color of JFormattedTextField on its input text not obeying the RegEx format of the formatter?

Comment: It's very difficult because the text field does not support text formatting. You need to implement a custom view (and UI) which supports something like this. But it can takes some days or weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the foreground color of the `JFormattedTextField` when the user attempts to change focus using an [`InputVerifier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification). Starting from this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2241997/230513), condition the color in your implementation of `shouldYieldFocus()`.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {
    if (verify(input)) {
        tf.setValue(date);
        tf.setForeground(Color.black);
        return true;
    } else {
        tf.setForeground(Color.red);
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image]

To see changes while typing, use a [`DocumentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) that evaluates `DateFormat` instances in a similar way.